# distributing apples and oranges into boxes. Confused about solution

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to discribute 4 identical oranges and 6 distinct apples into 5 distinct boxes

I know you find number of ways for apples which is 5^6.

The solution tells me that the ways for oranges is 8 choose 4.

You then multiply both of them together to get solution, which is 1,093,750

My question is....where does 8 come from, for 8 choose 4???

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as described in the [Help]. It may be appropriate on [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways you can stick the 4 identical oranges into 5 distinct boxes is the same as the number of nonnegative integer solutions to the problem:

> x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>3</sub> + x<sub>4</sub> + x<sub>5</sub> = 4

Suppose I take 4 1's and 4 separating +'s.  Then there is a one-to-one correspondence between orderings of 1's and +'s and solutions of the equation.

> For example, "1++11+1+" corresponds to "1 + 0 + 2 + 1 + 0".

There are 8! ways to order these 8 symbols, and because there are 4 identical 1's and 4 identical +'s we need to divide by 4! twice.

> 8! / (4! × 4!) = 8 choose 4

In general, the number of ways to put n identical objects into r distinct bins is [(n + r - 1) choose (r - 1)]. (r - 1 is referring to the number of "separating '+' symbols.")

Answer (score 0):

Although there is a easy mathematical solution I give you the programming solution because other answer would be of topic:

consider every possible arrangement of oranges in boxes, and do it with recursion:

1.no orange in the last box: it is similar to you have 4 similar oranges and 4 distinct boxes.

2.one orange in the last box: it is similar to you have 3 similar oranges and 4 distinct boxes.

and so on ...

now for making it to program use a function like this:

```
int orangeRecursion(int numOfOranges,int numOfBoxes){
    if(numOfOranges == 0)
       return 1;
    if(numOfBoxes == 0)
       return 0;
    int num = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<=numOfOranges ; i++){
        num += orangeRecursion(numOfOranges - i,numOfBoxes - 1)
    }
    return num;
}
```